# Is it possible to do item assignment for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: javascript

This is a typical `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0, numItems = array.length; i < numItems; ++i)
{
    var value = array[i];
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to include the `var value = array[i]` in the `for` loop line? Obviously there is no performance benefit from doing this. I'm mostly just curious.

This does **not** work:

```
for(var i = 0, numItems = array.length; i < numItems && value = array[i]; ++i)
{
    var value = array[i];
    ...
}
```

And I know about `array.forEach` but I prefer `for` for performance reasons because `forEach` has to make an extra `function` call for every iteration.

Comment: If you won't be using `i`, consider using a `for..of` loop instead to have this behavior automatically.

Comment: I do need the `i`. But I did some tests across all of the various array iteration options and a normal `for` loop seems to be the way fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the comma operator:

```
for(var i = 0, numItems = array.length, value; value = array[i], i < numItems; ++i)
```

That will perform the assignment in the "test" clause but it won't have any effect on the loop limit. Of course on the terminating test it'll assign `undefined`.

That's not really an idiomatic thing to do, in my experience, but to me it doesn't seem so terrible.